# is there any possibility to secure access to dashboard of jobrunr?

Tags: jobrunr

May u know any possibility to secure access to dashboard of jobrunr? As inside dashboard there are many critical operation can be done, it need be protected with user name and password. At the moment it seems it open for anyone who can access the dashboard's url.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can set username and password trough the following application properties

```
org.jobrunr.dashboard.username
org.jobrunr.dashboard.password
```

It enables a basic auth on Jobrunr Dashboard showed in the image

[Jobrunr Dashboard Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kEBo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend a setup where the dashboard can be accessed via the internet, I would only allow access via internal IP's.

If you also want to protect for internal IP's, there is a way to do so. Search the issues and the discussions for it (I'm not writing the answer here as I don't like to promote that solution).

**Update regarding JobRunr 6**

JobRunr Pro 6 will support OpenID Authentication.

Comment: Limit Ip is hard to accept...internal ip often change ...better intergrate with spring security with role check..